# Display Data in a Jtable upon Row Selection in Another JTable

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jtable

I'am working on a project which has-

**Details :**
1. I'am using a frame containing 3 panels laid North-Center-South containing :

- > Center Panel has a JTable whose data is displayed from a mysql database table[eg: Table1].
- > The South Panel has a tabbed pane with 3 tabs(each tab consisting a jtable in a scrollpane) initially containing no data but will display data from diffrent tables of the same database.[ Like.. Table2,Table3,Table4]
- > All the 4 tables[Table1,2,3,4] have a Common field "ID" present.

**Problem which i 'am facing :**
Now, i require to display data in the jtables(of South Panel's tabbed Pane) from different tables in the mysql database whenever the user selects a row in the Center Panels JTable[Table1].

I have this idea of getting the selected row's "ID" & calling a function which would filter the other tables like table2,3 & 4 and display the data in the South Panel. But,i'am in a fix and need some help as to how to do this friends.

Hoping to get a way which can help me in meeting the requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Ask the master table what its selected row is ([getSelectedRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29)). Convert this view row index to a model row index ([convertRowIndexToModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)). Ask the model for the data at this index, ands extract the ID of the data. The model should be a class that you wrote, extending `AbstractTableModel`. Then get the data to display in the three sub-tables from this ID, and change the model (or the data contained in the model) of these three tables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sir.. Will work on it as you suggested!